# Day convolution on the category of copresheaves on the opposite of a monoidal closed category

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

I asked this question on math.stackexchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871328) but didn't get an answer so I decided to ask it here too.

If $\mathcal{C}$ is symmetric monoidal closed, the Day convolution endows $[\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\mathbf{Set}]$ with a symmetric monoidal structure. I have not seen it stated anywhere (perhaps because it is just a matter of playing with definitions), but if, instead, $\mathcal{C}$ is co-closed, i.e. $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ is monoidal closed, can we make $[(\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}})^{\text{op}},\mathbf{Set}]=[\mathcal{C},\mathbf{Set}]$ co-closed too by some variant of the Day convolution?

Comment: Duality gives you a coclosed structure on $[\mathcal{C},\mathsf{Set}]^\mathrm{op}$, which is what you asked about in the stackexchange question.

Comment: $\mathcal{C}$ should be assumed to be small, otherwise the coends won't exist.